# Maya c++ API, animating an object in a thread

Tags: c++, maya, maya-api

I am trying to wrap my head around moving an object using the c++ Maya API.

I create a joint, using:

```
MFnIkJoint* rootJoint = new MFnIkJoint();
MObject rootTransform = rootJoint->create(MObject::kNullObj, &status);
```

Then I launch a thread that moves this joint:

```
bool dataStreamExit = false;
MStatus stat = MThreadAsync::init();
    if (MStatus::kSuccess != stat) {
        MString str = MString("Error creating MThreadAsync");
        MGlobal::displayError(str);
    }
    else
    {
        MThreadAsync::createTask(ApplyData, this, NULL, NULL);
    }
```

Where the thread function is:

`MVector currentCamPos;`

```
MThreadRetVal ApplyData(void* data)
{
    MStatus status;    

    while(dataStreamExit == false)
    {

        currentCamPos.x += 0.0001;      

        status = rootJoint->setTranslation(currentCamPos, MSpace::kTransform);

        Sleep(1);
      }
    return (MThreadRetVal)0;

}
```

I run this function, the joint is created in the viewport, and starts moving. Then, after a few seconds, it stops moving in the viewport, but the translation values in the attribute editor keep updating.

The thread keeps assigning data, but the viewport stops updating. I have tried this approach also:

```
MPlug plug = MFnDependencyNode(rootTransform ).findPlug("tx", false, &status);
if (status == true)
{
    plug.setFloat(currentCamPos.x);
}
```

But i see the same behavior. Do i need to refresh the view somehow after moving an object? How can I keep the viewport updating?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I need to update the viewport in the main Maya thread. This can be done using:

`MTimerMessage::addTimerCallback`

http://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2010help/API/class_m_timer_message.html

Comment: Even if this works in your case, you should be careful changing maya elements from another thread but the main thread. Maya can be quite picky and unless a class or method is not explictly marked as threadsafe. This can lead to undefined behaviour.